# OpenCL 1.2 no member Error in namespace cl

Tags: c++11, exception, opencl

I am trying to write an openCL 1.2 program based off examples I have found online and I'm encountering an error. Has the library changed to use std::exception now similar to std::vector?

With the snippet below:

```
 // Build the kernel
    cl::Program program(context, sources);
    try{
        program.build({device});
    } catch(cl::Error& e){
        std::cerr << program.getBuildInfo<CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG>(device) << std::endl;
        throw e;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using the command `program.build` wrong. It does not take the device list as input parameters, but rather a string of preprocessor options. Which device to use is already baked in the `context` object. Also it does return the error code. Try it like this:

```c
int error = program.build("-cl-fast-relaxed-math");
if(error) std::cerr << program.getBuildInfo<CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG>(device) << std::endl;
```

Here the example `"-cl-fast-relaxed-math"` is an option to switch off sanity checks for floating-point.